# Store a list of all class instances as a static array within the class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, instance

I am sure this has been asked before, but the terminology for the question is confusing, and I'm new enough top C++ I'm not even sure I'm using it correctly, so I haven't been able to find it previously asked.  Forgive me if I have missed it.

(If anyone is expert enough to correct my grammer in the question please do so, so that I may be more precise in the future ;-) )

I need to define a class wherein a member array stores pointers to all instances of said class.  The array is indexed by an integer id which every member has.

Thus an access to:

```
MyClass testcase = MyClass();
int i = testcase.id;
MyClass* tempVar;
tempVar = MyClass::InstanceRecord[i]; // this is the procedure in ?
```

should populate tempVar with a pointer to the newly created instance of the class 'testcase'.  In this way class members can refer to one another by their 'id' member.

My problem comes in declaring the array 'InstanceRecord'.  I cannot control the order in which the array is populated (in other words instances of the class are created), and there id numbers are pre-defined [paragraph edited].  Therefore I need to use the form: (NOTE: This is inside the class definition)

```
static MyClass* InstanceRecord[MAXIMUM_POSSIBLE_INSTANCES] = {x};
```

in order to declare the array, and populate the full width of the array in one step.  This way I can just alter the value of a given element of the array during the call to MyClass() (the constructor).

The problem is I don't know how to fill the array with memory pointers which do not already exist.  Would someone please be kind enough to explain to me what belongs on the right of my '=' in the previous statement, or give another way to do this?

EDIT:  The class definition looks like this:

```
class MyClass{
  Public:
    MyClass(string fileName){

      // Initialize class members from file data
      // including the id member

      // list of other members which require a status of True
      // before this item has an available of True.  id1-id5
      // represent id members of other instances of this class.
      // these id's all come from hard files.
      required_data[] = {id1, id2, id3, id4,id5};
      available=0; //boolean false
      status=0; //boolean false

      // is this the right way to do a vector of pointers?
      InstanceRecord[id]= this;
    }

    MyClass* get_instance_by_id(int i){
      return InstanceRecord[i];
    }

    bool is_available(){
      return available;
    }

    void update_available(){
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i<5 ;i++){
        if (InstanceRecord[required_data[i]].status == 1 || required_data[i] == 0){
          sum +=1;
        }
      }
      if (sum >=5){
        available = 1;
      }
    }

  Private:
    int id;
    std::vector<MyClass*>InstanceRecord (MAX_INSTANCES, nullptr);
    int required_data[5];
    bool status;
    bool available;
}
```

EDIT: A sample data file  (Comments not normally allowed but added for clarity)

```
Widget Glue Removal Tool  // becomes MyClass.name
1251                      // becomes MyClass.id
...lots of other stuff... // becomes MyClass.[some_var_name]
14,37,1841,15,27          // becomes the id1...id5 which must be
                          // status checked to determine this
                          // object's available flag.  These ints
                          // are the id's (like this 1251) of those
                          // other instances.
```

This data is actually for a pet project of mine which is a video game.  The class represents an item in a "Research Tree" where pre-requisite research must be completed before the new topic is available.  The tree and topics are not necessarily linear.  You might have to research items 20,400,12,and 15 before gaining access to item 47 (so instances whose ids are 20, 400, 12, and 15 would all have to have status=1 showing they were complete prior to item 47 having available = 1 showing it on the research project selection window).  Since the research tree is populated by reading every file in a directory, and thus in non controlled sequence, I need to populate my index vector with some kind of null pointer (assuming nullptr at the moment) when the first instance of the class is created.  My original question was, and essentially remains, how to fill the vector with this data.  I now know that

```
std::vector<MyClass*>InstanceRecord(MAX_POSSIBLE_INSTANCES, X);
```

Should fill my needs, but can nullptr replace the X in this line?

The Factory class in Barry's answer, has actually taught me much, but the next answer seems more suited my needs.  At this point I am simply trying to determine if Michaels answer can simply be modified to read:

```
id=<data read in from file>;
InstanceRecord[id]=this;
```

on lines five and six of his answer.

As I said, I'm only a dabbler in C++ and apparently my lack of a proper understanding of the terminology, and thus inability to state the problem well, has lead to some confusion.  Compile time to test this would be HUGE, so I'm hoping to get it as nearly bug free as possible (don't we all) before I start that process.

Comment: Raw pointers are considered bad practice in modern C++, you might want to look in to [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). And given the expandable nature of your InstanceRecord it may make sense to use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: If you are just trying to keep track of each instance of the class i believe that the answer from @Barry below will work.

Comment: It might at that, but I'm new enough to c++ that I am having to look this answer up line by line to understand it... ;-)

Comment: vector is being edited in.  It's definatly the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding the tracking vector as a static instance. 
You'll also need to remove the item from the tracking vector on destruction. And you'll need to lock it / unlock it appropriately if you're creating / updating from multiple threads.

It might looks a bit like this without locking.

```
class MyClass{
  Public:
    MyClass(string fileName){  
      status=0;
      id = instanceRecord.size();
      instanceRecord.push_back(this);          
    }

   ~MyClass() {
      //Clear it so that we dont access invalid data in update_available.
      instanceRecord[id]=NULL;
   }

    static MyClass* get_instance_by_id(int i){
      //TODO: Add bounds checking here.
      return instanceRecord.get(i);
    }    

    void update_available(){
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i<5 ;i++){
        MyClass * instance = instanceRecord[i];
        if(instance==NULL)
          continue;  
        if (instanceRecord[required_data[i]].status == 1 || required_data[i] == 0){
          sum +=1;
        }
      }
      if (sum >=5){
        available = 1;
      }
    }

  private:
    int id;
    static std::vector<MyClass*>instanceRecord;
    ...
}
```

You'll then need to add a `.cpp` file adding the static vector - something like this.

```
std::vector<MyClass> MyClass::instanceRecord = std::vector<MyClass>();
```

If you need locking, then you'll need to add a static lock object, and wrap all accesses to instanceRecord with that lock.

One final proviso is that if you're creating any instances of `MyClass` outside main you may run into the ["static initialization order fiasco"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) due to using a static variable. There are ways around this using certain singleton methods, but they make things look even more complicated, so are not worth it in simple cases.

Comment: This looks more like what I'm after, my only question is the 'id' assignment.  I Edited the question to add a sample data file (similar to what would be used to instantiate an object of the class), with comments to explain field usage.  Could you possibly review it and tell me how this would revise your suggestion?

Comment: If you're not using `id` as a sequential counter, but instead need that as an input, you'll need to switch from tracking in a `std::vector<MyClass*>` to `std::map<int,MyClass*>`. You'll probably also want to check for uniqueness of the id - for which you can use the map too.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is an object factory:

```
template <typename T>
class Factory {
private:
    static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> instances;

public:
    static T* create() {
        std::unique_ptr<T> obj{new T};
        obj->id = instances.size();
        instances.emplace_back(std::move(obj));
        return instances.back().get();
    }

    static T* get(size_t idx) const {
        return instances[idx].get(); 
    }
};
```

To be used like:

```
MyClass* testcase = Factory<MyClass>::create();
assert(testcase->id == 0);
assert(Factory<MyClass>::get(0) == testcase);
```

Comment: so if I understand this right ... I still define MyClass (like above but without the "tracking elements") and declare new instances of MyClass through class Factory (which serves to create the class instance of MyClass OUTSIDE of class Factory) and then do lookups for instance X of MyClass with Factory<MyClass>::get(x); which returns the pointer?

Comment: @Jase Pretty much. `MyClass` still needs `id` though.

Comment: This factory class looks interesting, but if I read this right it (Factory) is assigning an id based on sequence of creation.  Please look at my edited question (I flushed out the class example some more).  The update_available function is the entire reason I need these to work in a certain way.  Is there a way I can do this with a factory type class?

Comment: I know this is and old topic ... but I had error  undefined reference to Factory<MyClass>::instances